# Search functionality is not working with respect to Pagination in reactjs

Tags: arrays, reactjs, search, react-hooks, pagination

I am implementing a search functionality with respect to pagination. For example Pagination should update based on search. If there are 38 records for example that match with my search keyword, then pagination buttons should only go till 4 and my search input is working without pagination but I want the search input to work with respect to pagination. I don't know how can I fix it.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import React from 'react';
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate';

function UserTest() {
    const [record, setRecord] = useState([]);
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');

    const [usersPerPage] = useState(10);
    const [offset, setOffset] = useState(1);
    const [pageCount, setPageCount] = useState(0);    

    const getUserData = (data) => {
    return (
    <>
    <input type="text" onChange={(e) => { setSearchTerm(e.target.value) }} placeholder="Search" />
          <table>
           <thead>
           <tr>
              <th>PostId</th>
              <th>id</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Email</th>
            
            </tr> 
            </thead>
            <tbody>   
                {data && data.filter((val) => {
                    if (searchTerm === "") {
                      return val;
                    }
                    else if (
                      val.postId.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) ||
                      val.id.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) ||
                      val.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) ||
                      val.email.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) 
                      
                    ) {
                      return val;
                    }
                    return false;
                })
                .map((demo, i)=> {
                  return(
                    <tr key={i}>
                    <td>{demo.postId}</td>
                    <td>{demo.id}</td>
                    <td>{demo.name}</td>
                    <td>{demo.email}</td>
                  </tr>
                  )
                  })}
           </tbody>
         </table>
    </>
  );
}

const getAllPosts = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments")
    const data = res.data;
    
    const slice = data.slice(offset - 1 , offset - 1 + usersPerPage)
    console.log(58, slice);
    // For displaying Data
    const postData = getUserData(slice)
    // console.log(postData);
  
    // Using Hooks to set value
    setRecord(postData)
    setPageCount(Math.ceil(data.length / usersPerPage))
  }
  
  const handlePageClick = (event) => {
    const selectedPage = event.selected;
    setOffset(selectedPage + 1)
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getAllPosts()
  }, [offset]);
  

  return (
    <>
    <div className="main-app">
        
        {/* Display all the posts */}
        {record}

        {/* Using React Paginate */}
        <ReactPaginate
          previousLabel={"previous"}
          nextLabel={"next"}
          breakLabel={"..."}
          breakClassName={"break-me"}
          pageCount={pageCount}
          onPageChange={handlePageClick}
          containerClassName={"pagination"}
          subContainerClassName={"pages pagination"}
          activeClassName={"active"} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default  UserTest;
```